# How do I get the "name" from this JSON output (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json

I"m using `$.getJSON` and some otherstuff to get JSON data. I've finally achieved this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm1hizzfx02vioq/Screenshot%202015-06-07%2015.39.36.png?dl=0

To achieve this I've logged the json to the console with `console.log(projects[index]);` inside a `$.each()` statement. How do I now log the "name" string to the console.

I've tried `console.log(projects[index].name);` but that gives me `(2)undefined`

```
var usernameBehance = "stefkors";
var urlBehance      = 'https://www.behance.net/v2/users/stefkors/projects?callback=?&api_key=key';

$.getJSON(urlBehance, function(json){
    projects = json;
    outputBehanceContent();         // Behance Content
});

function outputBehanceContent() {
    $.each(projects, function(index){
        console.log(projects[index].name);
    });
};
```

Comment: your for each statement is an array with one array inside it like [[projects]]

Comment: This site is for programmers not graphic designers. Please post the related input and code not an image of it.

Comment: @EdwardKnowles Could you elaborate? If I understand correctly I would need to navigate on a different path?

Comment: @Vohuman I've added my code

Comment: Please show an example of the JSON response as well.

Comment: @h2ooooooo ok so I did a test with where I added a `var projects;` under `var urlBehance` it gave the same result as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects are stored in projects array so it should be json.projects
Here is a fiddle for iterating json array http://jsfiddle.net/f3baxkyd/1/

```
 $.getJSON(urlBehance, function(json){
    var arrayOfObjects = json.projects;
    $.each(arrayOfObjects, function(index){
        console.log(arrayOfObjects[index].name);
    });
   //console.log(json.projects);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! your solution worked! Having the json.projects instead of just json worked! I've added my own working solution, beceause a .each() would work better for my use.